# Differences in outcome between positioning of ss and t?

Tags: ffmpeg

What is the difference between

```
ffmpeg -y -ss 1 -i "test.MP4" -t 2 -c copy "test2.MP4"
```

and

```
ffmpeg -y -t 2 -i "test.MP4" -ss 1 -c copy "test2.MP4"
```

and

```
ffmpeg -y -ss 1 -t 2 -i "test.MP4" -c copy "test2.MP4"
```

and

```
ffmpeg -y -i "test.MP4" -ss 1 -t 2 -c copy "test2.MP4"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation on https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html:

> -ss position (input/output)
>
> When used as an input option (before -i), seeks in this input file to
>   position. [...] When used as an output option (before an output url),
>   decodes but discards input until the timestamps reach position.

and

> -t duration (input/output)
>
> When used as an input option (before -i), limit the duration of data
>   read from the input file. When used as an output option (before an
>   output url), stop writing the output after its duration reaches
>   duration.